# Help checking if number value in string is odd C#

Tags: c#, substring

I have the method `GetOption(5)` that returns the value `5K23` and I need to get the last two characters of the string the thing is the value is a string value, so I would need to use `Substring` I have tried doing:

```
if( Convert.ToInt32(GetOption(5).Substring(GetOption(5).Length-2, 2) % 2 == 1) )
```

I can't seem to get it right, can anyone help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check it using a regular expression? Something like `^.*[0-9][13579]$`

Comment: @khachik I dunno about "better", but I like it. Could also just do `[13579]$`, to "align with the title".

Comment: @pst, "better" here means "faster" and putting less burden to the GC.

Comment: @khachik I usually measure "better" by "ease to understand and maintain", in which case I agree that the Regex is more clear than the code in the post, even if there are other alternatives ;-) I don't even consider the other "better" until after I've dug out the profiling... but then I don't write XNA games for the XBox or do any mobile development.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really need last two digits to determine whether number is odd

```
var option = GetOption(5);
var isOdd = int.Parse(option[option.Length - 1].ToString()) % 2 == 1;
```

Comment: `s/you don't really/you don't at all/`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me, if I do if(isOdd) it throws out an error. Input string is not in correct format

Comment: @Sandeep are you sure that `option` contains `"5K23"` when that happens?

Comment: OK I gave it a try, set a breakpoint and there was a problem when setting length-1 I changed it to 2 instead to just skip the first two characters. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = "5K23";
var regex = new Regex(@"\d{2}$");
var match = regex.Match(t);
if (match.Success)
{
    var extracted = match.Value;
    // Do more stuff
}
```

Comment: I find the regular expression here *much* more readable and intuitive than the Substring approach -- although I would just use [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz.aspx) here. That Perlesque semi-quote isn't terribly justified here, IMOHO ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I like [@Lukáš' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471877/help-checking-if-number-value-in-string-is-odd-c/6471934#6471934) (+1) but the *reason* your code doesn't work is...

```
Convert.ToInt32
(
    GetOption(5).Substring
    (
        GetOption(5).Length-2, 2
    ) % 2 == 1
)
```

**Incorrect paren grouping.** You're passing `<long thing> % 2 == 1` to `Convert.ToInt32()`.

Try to keep lines short and readable.

```
var s = GetOption(5);
if(Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(s.Length-2, 2)) % 2 == 1)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: The indexes passed to SubString in the OP are fine.  You want to start at len-2 for 2 characters.  starting for len-2 and copying len characters is incorrect and will throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: You're right, I assumed that `Substring()` with 2 int arguments worked the same in C# as in Java (I'm a Java guy). Clearly this was incorrect! Edited accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int x;
    string option = GetOption(5);
    if (Int32.TryParse(option.Substring(option.Length - 2), out x) && x % 2 == 1)
```